# Can we setup email alert for export reports

Tags: apex, community, email, reporting

Hi friends i got a requirement like when anyone export any report from sfdc.

I want to notify a user through email.Like this user had export a report from sfdc.

But i didn't find any solution.I thought it is not possible from sfdc.

Comment: You can get who ran what report 24 hours after the fact using [Event Monitioring.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) However, this does come at an additional cost, and won't allow you to send out an email as the user clicks export.

Comment: is this  a compliance/security use case?

Comment: Hey @cropredy It's a security use case in my organisation.Is there any possibility to notify when any user export report from salesforce.